# How can I open SQL Server View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to open SQL Server Views in MVC, but I can't do this, I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Diagram has been created, but my views not created.

SQL Server view that I mean:

[image: SQL Views]

And my model just like this: 
[image: my Diagram]

I got this Warning.

> Warning        Error 6013: The table/view 'PTILIMS.dbo.VW_WAYBILL_BY_STATUS' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

But I use views, not table, hy I must have a primary key?

---- I GOT MY ANSWER, SORRY ----
the answer is used ISNULL in query to make field as primary key in edmx

Answer (score 0):

Go through this`link`,i hope it will helpful for you.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access

Comment: Link-only answers are advised against. Please, at minimum, summarize what's said in the linked page. Links can change or become invalid, which would render your answer useless.